# Deserialize HttpResponseMessage of Soap:Envelope to C# Object

Tags: c#, xml, object, soap, httpresponsemessage

I'm calling `Soap` method and receiving `HttpResponseMessage` as below :

```
HttpResponseMessage createResponse = await ExecuteMyEndPoint(endpoint, requestXMLstring, client);
```

And reading that as a String Response:

```
string responseMessage = await createResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This is the Sample Response :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:createWorkflowResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/workflow">
         <WorkflowExternalReference xmlns:ns3="http://www.somedomain.com/xml/integration">123456789</WorkflowExternalReference>
      </ns1:createWorkflowResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to convert this response to C# object. How to do that?

Comment: Simplest way is to parse with XDocument : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string);